# question regarding proper mathematical form

Tags: education

Hi there say I have the following two sums:

$$A=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k$$

$$B=\sum_{k=0}^{n}2 \cdot k$$

where $n \rightarrow \infty$, should I write that as

$$A=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k, \quad n \rightarrow \infty$$

$$B=\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2 \cdot k, \quad n \rightarrow \infty$$

or is there a better way of writing it?

Comment: Something called the limit. Can we evaluate this at $\infty$? Also just put it at top of sum.

Comment: I know this happens at limit, but how do I write it properly?

Comment: Aside from the comments below ($\infty$ on the top) another way of writing this would be: $$\sum_{k}k$$ This simply means "Sum over all $k$" and if no limit is defined, is a valid way of writing.

Answer (score 2):

$A=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} k$ and similarly for $B$.

Comment: I just thought in general it was bad form to write $\infty$ in a sum, is the way I wrote it wrong?

Comment: Nope, not wrong, just different.

Comment: @nonein I remember it being emphasized in one of my early advanced math classes that it was actually a limit, but in the literature it's 99% going to just use $\sum^\infty$

Comment: Yep in the early math classes we were not allowed to write it down as I did either in order to understand that $\infty$ is not a limit. But as time passed noone really cared anymore.. :D

Answer (score 2):

You might write

$$
A_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k
$$

and then
$$
A = \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k .
$$

But knowing how to write it doesn't make it right. This limit does not exist. You can't add up all the integers starting at $0$.

You might say "$A = \infty$" but that's just shorthand for the fact that the sum grows without bound. "Infinity" is not a number.

Comment: Oh yeah I know that, it was purely for illustrative purposes, I have just seen some people write it similar to how I wrote it in articles, is that an incorrect way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

The full version is:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^n 2k\right)$$

However, we write this as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2k$$ for short.

In words, you might like to say "The limit of
$$\sum_{k=0}^n 2k$$
as $n$ tends to infinity."

Answer (score 0):

Something called the limit. Can we evaluate this at $\infty$? Also just put it at top of sum. $$A=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}k$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\displaystyle A =\sum_{k=1}^n k$ then you could write
\begin{align}
& \lim_{n\to\infty} A = \text{something} \\[10pt]
\text{or } & A \to \text{something as } n\to\infty \\[10pt]
\text{or } & \sum_{k=1}^n k \to \text{something as } n \to\infty \\[10pt]
\text{or } & \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n k = \text{something} \\[10pt]
\text{or (since this is a sum) } & \sum_{k=1}^\infty k = \text{something}.
\end{align}